# Bit order when assigning SystemVerilog struct directly to a logic type

Tags: system-verilog

SystemVerilog has packed struct where VHDL has record. Unlike VHDL that requires an explicit conversion between a record and std_logic_vector, SystemVerilog is able to make an implicit conversion.

I have 2 questions about this feature

1. For a given packed struct, how is the bit decided when it is assigned to a logic type?

   typedef struct packed {
   bit [7:0]  addr;
   bit        valid;
   bit [31:0] data;
   } mem_pkt;
2. Is it possible to force SystemVerilog to not permit implicit conversion for all packed struct or maybe specific struct?

Answer (score 1):

Packed data always goes from MSB to LSB in field declaration order. If you declare

```
mem_pkt pkt;
```

Then `pkt.addr[7]` corresponds to `pkt[39]` and `pkt.addr[0]` corresponds to `pkt[32]`. `pkt.data[0]` corresponds to `pkt[0]`.

Verilog is a weakly typed language and there is no way prevent assignments from packed arrays and structs to one another without some kind of linting tool. Use unpacked structs if you want strong type safety. Simply wrapping your packed struct as one field of an unpacked struct can achieve that.

```
typedef struct packed { bit [7:0] addr; bit valid; bit [31:0] data; } pkt;
typedef struct {pkt_t m} mem_pkt;
```